# How to send v-for computed data as parameter to function on Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

I feel like this is a somewhat specific question that I can't find the answer anywhere. Perhaps there's something I'm missing about Vue.JS that can solve this issue for me.

I'm looking to create a small single page application that changes screens dynamically using parameters. In theory, the app should be dynamic and I should be able to update the Database without touching the Vue.js app.

I have a small JSON database with an array of information on it.

```
["mary","john","alice"]
```

On a children component using the lifecycle hook `beforeMount()` I'm retrieving this information and placing it into an array on `Data`.

```
data() {
    return {
        names: [],
    }
},

/*...*/

beforeMount() {
    var namesDB = require('../assets/db/names.json');
    this.names = names;
}
```

With that array, I'm creating a few buttons

```
<button v-for="name in names">{{ name }}</button>
```

This creates a button for each name fine without issues.

What I'm looking to do now, is to be able to send the retrieved name (`{{ name }}`) to a function on methods. The purpose later is to send this to the parent app to change the screen for the desired person, but for now, it's something simple like this:

```
methods: {
    say(nameParam) {
        console.log(nameParam);
    },
},
```

I **thought** of doing something like the following:

```
<button v-for="name in names" @click="say('{{ name }}')">{{ name }}</button>
```

However, I found this doesn't work, as the console returns: `{{ name }}`.

How can I send this type of computed data as a parameter, and furthermore, how can I use the computed data for the parent component to change the screen of the application? (say, I want to use the name to check for a specific person).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use interpolated values in attributes in Vue. Click handlers are interpreted as a javascript expression, and `name` is in your scope in a `v-for` so just do this.

```
<button v-for="name in names" @click="say(name)">{{ name }}</button>
```

Comment: Oh my god, you're right. I can't believe I hadn't thought of that. I guess this question was sillier than I thought.

Comment: @concheria It's a common stumbling block, really. Don't sweat it.

Comment: yeah, interpolations inside attributes is easily the most common cause for questions in the vue.js tag

Comment: @matt probably neck and neck with using `this` correctly.